# Is it ok to ask the same question here and in another Stack Excange site, such as Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

So, yeah, is that OK, or if not how do I make sure people from both communities get to see it?

Comment: Cross-posting [is not permitted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) anywhere in the SE network.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally no, it is not okay to cross post.

If it doesn't get answered here, or the community feels it is off topic then we can migrate it over somewhere more appropriate.